# Is there a way to capture info displayed in a running Android app?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm playing a game, and I'm trying to get the full name of my opponent.  The problem is that his name is so long that it only displays a shortened version : "username_6475..." Adjusting my devices' display does nothing.  Is there a way to print all info displayed in an app... Maybe similar to "view-source" in a browser?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, You can achieve this by using Marquee in TextView.**

**Xml:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/marque_scrolling_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Create a Marquee (Scrolling Text) in Android Using TextView. Android Marquee (Scrolling Text) Tutorial with Example"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
```

**Java:**

```
TextView marque = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.marque_scrolling_text);
marque.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Yes this will achieve the results I was asking for...I now realize that I was a bit vague in my question tho.  I am looking for a 3rd party app that could display this info... Maybe similar to logcat, but instead it dumps whatever the app is displaying in text format